# Bootstrap Table Row Bad Sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image] 
I can't correctly format a table using Bootstrap. I checked this code many times, and I don't know why it doesn't look correct.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Mecz</th>
        <th>Liga</th>
        <th>Kurs</th>
        <th>Data Rozpoczęcia</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
            <th scope="row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0px;">
                <div id="accordion" class="collapse" style="padding: 5px;">Hidden</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it because you're trying to close a `<th>` with a `</td>`? `<th scope="row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>`

Comment: Still not working, but i correct it

Comment: It's working on jsfiddle correctly, i use bootstrap.min.css from https://bootswatch.com/flatly/

Comment: It's working on bootply also: http://www.bootply.com/0nMtYZe7l2 - do you have some other CSS that may be affecting it?

Comment: Yeah, i told it two commens high. I change the bootstrap.min.css to old -> it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're code seems to be working fine aside from the th inside tbody which has been closed by a td tag. made a correction on the html code to fix that. Another thing to check is there might be another styling rules that seems to override your table styling. you can try to disable other stylesheet and just leave bootstrap to see if it will fix your issues.

Below is a working demo of your table.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Mecz</th>
        <th>Liga</th>
        <th>Kurs</th>
        <th>Data Rozpoczęcia</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion" class="clickable">
            <td scope="row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0px;">
                <div id="accordion" class="collapse" style="padding: 5px;">Hidden</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```